# How to pass an interface to Java from Unity code?

Tags: c#, java, android, unity, jni

First, let me say that this is my first experience with Unity, so the answer may be right under my nose. I've also posted this question on Unity's answers site, but plugin questions don't seem to be as frequently answered there.

I'm trying to create a plugin that allows me to access an SDK from my game. I can call SDK methods just fine using `AndroidJavaObject` and I can pass data to them with no issue. But there are some SDK methods that require an interface to be passed.

For example, my Java function:

```
public void attemptLogin(String username, String password, LoginListener listener);
```

Where `listener`; is a callback interface. I would normally run this code from Java as such:

```
attemptLogin("username", "password", new LoginListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        //Yay! do some stuff in the game
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int error) {
        //Uh oh, find out what happened based on error
    }
});
```

Is there a way to pass a C# interface through JNI/Unity to my `attemptLogin` function? Or is there a way to create a mimic-ing interface in C# that I can call from inside the Java code (and pass in any kind of parameter)?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Main Unity selling point is that it is cross platform. What this means for your question is that I would strongly suggest not calling SDK functions directly, but doing as much as possible through Unity provided API's. In short do the authentication using Unity API. This way, you will write connectivity code once, and it will work on all platforms. Unity will take care of the platform differences. In particular look at:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/net-SocialAPI.html

If you really need to interoperate C# and Java, I am sorry but my answer is lacking on this.

Comment: This is true, but in this case I am writing the plugin, not the game ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Did not get that from the question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since Unity 4.2 there is a class called [Androidjavaproxy](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaProxy.html) which can do exactly what you are looking for.

This class can implements any Java interface in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by your use of the term "interface", since that is a keyword that C# responds to. However, when you described a "callback interface" I realized you're talking about something different: a way for the Java code to call functions in Unity (rather than only the other way around).

This is done using the command UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage (imported into Java by including Unity's classes.jar file). This command will invoke methods on a named object. So for example, `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName", "MethodName", "Message to send")` would call MethodName() on the object GameObjectName, and pass the message to that method.

To ensure that my custom plugins have an object to send messages to, I usually have my plugin scripts create an object named something like MyPlugin_instance and use DontDestroyOnLoad() to make sure that object is never removed from the scene. That code looks like:

```
public class TestPlugin : MonoBehaviour {
   private static TestPlugin _instance;
   public static void Initialize() {
      if (_instance != null) {
         Debug.Log("TestPlugin instance was found. Already initialized");
         return;
      }
      Debug.Log("TestPlugin instance not found. Initializing...");
      GameObject owner = new GameObject("TestPlugin_instance");
      _instance = owner.AddComponent<TestPlugin>();
      DontDestroyOnLoad(_instance);
   }
rest of class...
```